# ¿Porque la api de google maps no funciona en un servidor? [Error: The Geolocation service failed]

Tags: javascript, google-maps, api

Actualmente acabo de subir lo que tengo de mi sitio web a un servidor de prueba y que es gratuito, de forma local si funciona la `api` de `google maps` y me muestra la ubicación en la que me encuentro actualmente. Pero cuando subí mi sitio web al servidor y modifico todo lo necesario para que todo se viera bien, esa parte de la api de `google maps` dejo dejo de funcionar correctamente.

codigo de la api de google maps:

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };


            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Esta es tu ubicacion');
            map.setCenter(pos);


            var icon = {
    url: "vista/multimedia/imagenes/pointer.png", // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                title: 'marker with infoWindow',
                icon: icon
           });
           marker.addListener('click', function() {
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
          });


          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      }
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente: `Error: The Geolocation service failed` y no modifique nada de el `script`, ese se quedo intacto.

Código para poner el mapa de google:

```
<center><div id="map" style="height:500px;width:900px;margin-top:5%;"></div></center>
```

Código para mandar llamar la api con su respectiva key

```
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA49iAee5kSTQ-whGT3A77H-PJsK5FzLCk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Revisa la url donde insertas la api de google, debes tener una key de dicha api para poder utilizarla en un dominio. Eso se pone en la url del <script> de la api googlemaps. Lo tienes puesto?

Comment: @Jakala si ya lo tenia en el código, lo agregue a la publicación

Answer (score 1):

Ese mensaje te sale porque en tu navegador has denegado los permisos de geolocalizarte.

En el código JavaScript donde haces la llamada a `navigator.geolocation` debes comprobar si el usuario ha dado permiso al navegador para que informe a tu código JavaScript de tu geolocalización.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = {
       lat: position.coords.latitude,
       lng: position.coords.longitude
    };


    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent('Esta es tu ubicacion');
    map.setCenter(pos);


    var icon = {
        url: "vista/multimedia/imagenes/pointer.png", // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
    };
} else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't supports Geolocation or you denied the permission to geolocalizate your device");
}
```

Actualmente ya tienes una parte del código que gestiona cuando el navegador no tiene geolocalización o se han denegado los permisos. Se hace en la línea

```
handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
```

Y es la que te saca el punto en el mapa con el mensaje `Error: The Geolocation service failed`